Krull dimension of modules of tensor products with $\mathbb{Q}$
Let $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$ be the ring of polynomials in $n$ variables over the integers. Let $M$ be a nontrivial finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$ which is torsion free as an abelian group (i.e. $am\neq 0$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}-0$ and all $m$ in $M-0$). Let $k=\dim M$, the Krull dimension of $M$. Is it true that $\dim(M\otimes \mathbb{Q})=k-1$ as a $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,...,X_n]$-module? If so do you know where I might find a reference?

If you are assuming that $M \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is a tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$-modules (I'll use $R$ to denote $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$), then I guess dimension of $M$ is not really as expected. We may have $$M \otimes_{R} \mathbb{Q} = M \otimes_R \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{Z} \otimes_R M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{Z} \otimes_R (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q})$$
Now let $M= R$, then $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]$. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ can be viewed as $R/(x_1,...,x_n)$,  $\mathbb{Z} \otimes_R \mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n] = \mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1,...,x_n) = \mathbb{Q}$, whose Krull dimension is zero as a $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]$-module.
If we are using tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, then  $\text{Ann}(M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}) = \text{Ann}(M) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$, while the ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the ideals in $R$ generated only by non-constant polynomials. As a result,  $$\dim R/\text{Ann}(M )  = \dim \mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]/\text{Ann}(M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}) +1$$

Thank you!, I did indeed mean tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$ modules. I have one more question, why does the equality result follow from the 1 to 1 correspondence of ideals generated by nonconstant polynomials?

Maybe I should put it like this: $\mathbb{Q}[x_,...,x_n]$ can be viewed as a localization of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $\mathbb{Z}-{0}$ is the corresponding multiplicatively closed subset. Then we can understand the ideals in the localization, which are in 1-1 correspondence with ideals generated by non-constant polynomials.

We also know that a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n] $ is of the form $(I,p)$ where $I$ is generated by non-constant polynomials and $p$ is a prime, so we may have that $\text{ht}I = \text{ht}(I,p)-1$.
